# How to get sun Rise/Set hour using GPS data and Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino

Working with young students, We try to build a system that calculate Sun Rise/Set in any place of the globe
The idea is to get basic data from GPS (including date and geografic data) and to process it in the Arduino Mega card
Output data will be transmitted using Wi-Fi 
Please advice for code to process GPS data to Sun Rise/Set time

Comment: This isn't really a free code writing service.  There are myriad tutorials on the internet that will help you get the GPS and time data from whatever GPS module you have.  Beyond that calculating sun rise and set times is a mathematical problem, not really a programming one.  You'll have to research that math first.  Once you know the equations, doing the calculations with a processor is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile an Arduino sketch for the Mega, it gets linked not only
to the Arduino core library, but also to avr-libc. You can then use any
of the functions defined in avr-libc. And this library happens to
provide what you are looking for in `<time.h>`:

- [`set_position()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html#ga90f87ccc97456fe3dcd867ccf71538ee): Set the geographic coordinates of
  the 'observer', for use with several of the following functions.
- [`sun_rise()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html#ga21a491a92bce972d041e2194b4577943): Return the time of sunrise, at the location
  of the observer.
- [`sun_set()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html#ga0865e7b9f075981fafaabd0964de2d7f): Return the time of sunset, at the location of
  the observer.